# What sampler i can user for Restful services in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Am using restful services and i wanted to test services just by sending an xml format request with base url as target url,i tried by using xml-RPC request and its working fine.

but i came to know that we should not use XML-RPC request for restful services request  and it should be a rest sampler but am not seeing this in jmeter.

please suggest me which sampler i can use in jmeter for restful services?

its normal flow like CRUD

Comment: If answer is OK for you you should accept it so that users can trust it. ANd upvote :-)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use HTTP Sampler with Raw  Post body.

Add a Header Manager as a child to set correct content-type.

Comment: How it is different with XML-RPC request ? what kind of problems i can see if user XML-RPC sampler ? don't mind a asking all these bcz of need to explain to my superiors why i choose only this?

Comment: More efficient and performing. xml-rpc is very old and has far less options.

Comment: Agreed XML-RPC is old but how i can user HTTP sampler more efficiently than rpc ?

Comment: What do you mean by more efficiently ?

Answer (score 0):

REST Architecture mainly works on HTTP GET and POST method exchanges.

1. capture the service call URL (inspect element and network tab in your browser)

2.Check for Parameters being passed

3.Check for GET/POST method

Include the same in your HTTP request and add a listner. It is actually more easier and effective than xml-rpc calls as jmeter is built on java.

refer--- [offcial docs for http request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)

and blazemeter docs is an excellent collection of jmeter references.